# How to implement table completion into form

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to make an app that has the user fill out a form. There are several parts (4) to this form so the current workflow has the user complete a section, then save it to the table view using core data.

This process is repeated for the next three sections. I am wondering how to implement a checked box or something similar when one of the parts get completed.

Eventually once all four are done, I want to be able to export the information in those four forms into a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is have a `UITableView` which each cell is a section. When user tap on a cell, it brings the user to the corresponding form and let the user to fill info.

The cells in `UITableView` can display check marks by doing something like

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

You can google or find stack overflow posts related to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and how to implement them.

You can save the `indexPath` of checked cell and check if all sections have been filled or not.